# Make UICollectionViewController paged sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, sections

I'm making a collectionView where 1 section means 1 calendarday, I want to make it paged so it only shows 1 section (1 day) at a time so i can swipe (scroll) to the left or right to show me the next day.

I cant seem to find a solution or im dont know the right keywords...

im mainly using the storyboard and my collectionViewController is embedded in a ContainerView in a normal UIViewController.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: keyword is-`UIPageViewController`, Just use one View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to work with the scrollView. It easer and faster